# Want to edit the HTML/PHP of a Wordpress Widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Basically, in my theme there is called a `top-widget` which allows you to add a menu, which is made up of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. I really want to edit the HTML of this

setup it has going, and add a few more things (like custom fields to them).

The farthest I was able to trace it was this line:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top_widget_left' ); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top_widget_middle' ); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top_widget_right' ); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

More specifically the `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top_widget_left' ); ?>`. Any possible idea what file/location this is calling?

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on how it's regireted. For more detail: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars

If you want to find it, use [TextCrawler](https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html) to find where it's registered in your script

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in widget action hook of your theme function.php

```
<?php
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Custom Widget',
    'id' => 'custom-widget',
    'description' => 'Appears in the Home area',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
?>
```

For calling in your theme any page widget use this code:

```
<?php
    if(is_active_sidebar('custom-widget'))
    {
        dynamic_sidebar('custom-widget');
    }
?>
```